# Socket Programming : how to receive data until a dot is received (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, networking, recv

Situation:
I am currently writing a client program with a provided server program
I need to send the command 'READ' and get a bunch of data from server

The server will just keep sending and lastly it will sd a dot
(".")
My task is to display all msg it send out (tgt with the dot)
I can successfully receive everything and displayed.
however i cannot exit the while loop(cannot successfully detect the dot)
Why is that?
Below is my code. thanks!

```
def READ(mySocket):

    op="READ"
    clientSocket.send(op.encode())

    while(True):
        try:
            rcvmsg = clientSocket.recv(4096)
            print("Server:{} ".format(rcvmsg.decode()))
            if (rcvmsg.decode() == "."):
                break
        except :
            print("some error happen" )
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: What do you see if you print out `rcvmsg` without calling `decode` on it?

Comment: for the dot , i see b'.\x00'

Comment: take a look at this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995319/how-to-send-incoming-messages-from-socket-client-to-gui-pyqt5)

Comment: Strange, it seems like the server isn't just sending a dot, it's sending a dot plus the invisible NUL character. The quick fix would be to do `if (rcvmsg.decode() == ".\x00"):`, but it would be much better to figure out why the server is adding that extra byte, and make it stop.

Comment: It works. thank you very much!! :)

Comment: Note that TCP is a streaming protocol and has no concept of message boudaries.  If the server calls `send('Hello')` and `send('.')` you *could* receive `'Hello.'` in one `recv(4096)`.  Also, the server may have a bug sending a null (`'\x00'`) but it could be starting another message and you're getting a byte from it.  You should buffer your data (and not decode) until your buffer contains a dot, then extract the message and decode.